# Implementing android chat module using long polling

Tags: java, android, wcf, long-polling, instant-messaging

I am writing an Android app that among features has a chat module. I have choose to implement the chat using long polling.

Because I am trying to avoid eating up the user phone battery I thought about adding to the implementation a GCM messages platform to notify the device about new messages.

The idea is to use long polling while the user has the app open on his screen so engaging in a real time chat would be fast and does not involve sending a lot of GCM messages, while when idle, the server will know that the user is not currently polling and will send the device a GCM message to wake it up when a new message arrives.

I am struggling with a few issues implementing this method:

1. What is the best way to know the status of the user - Is hes polling right now or waiting for the push message to wake it up. Should I set the app to notify the server when it goes to sleep or the server should detect it by itself?
2. If I set it so the app will notify the server when to switch between modes, how do I recover in cases this notification did not got through. (when the client is waiting for gcm and the server thinks it's polling and will not send one..)
3. I experienced some case where the client was polling and the server did not responded even when it got new messages. Maybe some kind of timeout on the server that the client is not aware of... If that's a bug I'll fix it, but what can I do in cases when the client thinks it's polling while the server does not know about it (the timeout of the requests is too long to wait for the next poll).

My client is native Android and the Webservice is WCF (C#).

Any thought will help.

Comment: Your question is well written, but has a few problems that may make it hard to get answers on SO. You ask three different questions in one. In addition it's very open-ended, as opposed to the more practical "answerable" question that's typically preferred (asking "should I ...." is not very answerable, all answers would have to start with "it depends"). This also makes your question quite "localized" (i.e. very specific to your case).

Comment: Perhaps you could split it up in three questions, and work a bit on making them less open-ended, answerable and as non-localized as possible.

Comment: Thought about splitting it to more then 1 question but all the section refers to the same problem - Instant messaging protocol implementation for mobile apps. Because each question depends on all other answers I choose to write it all as one big issue.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used GCM but i have experience with lots of messaging applications on mobile so will try to explain what we followed.

> > What is the best way to know the status of the user

First off - long poll when app is in front isn't the best way to receive instant message. You need to keep a tcp connection open to receive it instantly ! ( hopefully your notification should also contain the message ) Any kind of polling will ensure that you wasting battery and not receving *instant* messages.
Second - I would think that client should inform the server about its state ( foreground/background ) so server knows how to respond.
So my suggestion would be to use TCP socket for CIR and use poll as backup when in background  ( in case server loses the "client went to background message" )

1. To recover use long poll (10 minutes) to get updates from server and also informing server about your state.
2. If you use the approach i have mentioned ( using tcp socket ) the server should know that your app is in foreground as long as the connection alive. Also a server should always respond to the poll with delta updates ( your poll should send last time the server sent something )

Hope this helps.

Comment: The long poll when app is in front is because I want to use HTTP to poll. Keeping a TCP connection open from a mobile app to a remote server is not so trivial, this is why I am going the way jabber protocol (gtalk, whatsup, facebook) is working.

Comment: The server always keeps the last message id that was sent to the client so it could send only delta updates. And in the first login of each session the client is able to modify this counter to recover messages it might lost.